# Angularjs infinite loop when changing url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location, router

Got an issue with angular and angular-route.
Don't know why, if i'm navigating in my app all is working fine. But if i change the hash url directly from nav (or make an history.back) all crashes because it tries to resolve infinitly.

Here is my router :
myApp.conf

```
ig(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/news', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/news.html',
                controller: 'NewsController',
                resolve: { load: function(DataService) { return DataService.load(); } }
            }).
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/accueil.html',
                controller: 'HomeController',
                resolve: { load: function(DataService) { return DataService.load(); } }
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }
]);
```

DataService.load() is a service that is working pretty well except for my problem

```
    load: function () {
        console.log("DataService.load()");
        console.log($location.path());

        if(this.deferred !== null)
            this.deferred.resolve();

        this.newPage = true;
        this.deferred = $q.defer();

        if($location.path() == this.previousUrl) {
            this.deferred.resolve();
        }
        else {
            this.previousUrl = $location.path();

            // If it's first load, do it directly without wait $interval
            if (this.firstLoad) {
                this.checkDatas();
            }

            // All is already done (asynchronous loading data)
            this.loadCheck();
        }

        alert("DataService loaded");
        return this.deferred.promise;
    }
```

I've found a lot of persons with this kind of problem (or more digest problem) but no solution. I can see my alert() pop infinitly and it try to resolves it again and again and again...

Thx for ideas

Comment: create a plubker to debug. don't make us debug in head.

Comment: Use angular ui router instead of ngRoute, it is better solution for routes as it handles nested views/states, so you can add one top level abstract state and resolve loading there, and you will not be forced to resolve loading in two states. You can try it and add corresponding new question if any.

Comment: Thx for the tip. I've changed to angular ui route. That's a bit better, but now i've having a digest infinite loop. Good news : does not crash navigator. Bad news : still impossible to get history change.